Facebook Graph API - Event Manager - Get Events
I currently have a Data Set under Data Sources for which I have a Meta Pixel that records Standard Events such as View, Lead and Purchase.
I'm able to view these by logging into Facebook and going to Events Manager then Data Sources and selecting the Date Set.
Events Manager allows the ability to View Details, a summary, of the Events that were recorded.
I would like to download a subset of these Events based on a filter, including information such as the Event Parameters, but unfortunately Events Manager only provides Sampled Activities and excludes the Event Parameters.
Is it possible to retrieve all of the Events, including Event Parameters, for a filtered list using the Graph API?
I've done a search for Graph API and Events Manager but all I get is links to pulling information about Facebook Page Event.
Any help appreciated, thank you in advance!!!
EDIT:
I've found something that looks promising, Get events from Facebook Graph API, this answer helped me pull aggregated/summary event information but is it possible to pull granular/detailed event information using the Graph API?
